# How to use diff for files names, not file content, and echo "differences!"

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, grep

Background:
While comparing 2 directories,
command1, from the internet:

```
diff <(find "$DIR1" -printf '%P\n' | sort) <(find "$DIR2" -printf '%P\n' | sort) | grep '^[<>]'
```

was 307 times faster than command2:

```
diff -rq --no-dereference "$DIR1" "$DIR2" && echo "no difference" || echo "differences!"
```

command1 was 307 times faster and
based on a computer with a directory having
88000 files
1000 GB

command1: checks file names, not file content, a fast compare.
command2: checks file content but took a factor of 307x more time.

command3 = command1 + echo results:

```
diff <(find "$DIR1" -printf '%P\n' | sort) <(find "$DIR2" -printf '%P\n' | sort) | grep '^[<>]' && echo "no difference" || echo "differences!" ;
```

Question:
How to correctly echo `"differences!"` between 2 directories
because command3 output is
wrong saying `"no difference"` when there are `"differences!"`
because one file `(empty.txt)` is put in one directory not both:

```
> empty.txt 
no difference
```

script:

```
DIR1="/media/x/8001G_GPTEXT4/Test1/E BOOKS"
DIR2="/media/x/2000G_DOSNTFS/Test1/E BOOKS"
diff <(find "$DIR1" -printf '%P\n' | sort) <(find "$DIR2" -printf '%P\n' | sort) | grep '^[<>]' && echo "no difference" || echo "differences!" ;
diff -rq --no-dereference "$DIR1" "$DIR2" && echo "no difference" || echo "differences!" ;
```

details:
`neofetch --stdout |grep 'OS:'`
OS: Kubuntu 22.04.3 LTS x86_64

Again,
How to use `diff` for files names, not file content, and
echo `"differences!"`

--

Comment: `grep '^[<>]'` in your "command3" returns exit status 0 (success) when there is a difference. For now it seems to me the whole problem is because you got the logic backwards.

Comment: How to confirm what command the exit status belongs to?  
Said differently, How to confirm "command3" returns 
exit status 0 (success) belongs to 
```diff``` or ```find``` or ```printf``` or ```sort``` or ```grep```?

Comment: The exit status of "command3" [comes from `echo` executed last](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Lists.html). `&&` therein depends on the exit status of the preceding pipeline. The exit status of the pipeline [comes from `grep`, unless `pipefail` is enabled](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pipelines.html).